# Anonymous users receive 401 Unauthorized / must sign in response with Rails 3, Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, anonymous

In an open source Rails application using Devise, I have been unable to allow anonymous users read access to resources. It seems like Devise/Warden is getting involved and throwing rejection logic before CanCan may get involved.

I only need anonymous users to have list and read access to documents and annotations models.

### Attempt

I pulled some routes out of the `authenticated :user` code block to prevent immediate rejection by Devise.

```
    # config/routes.rb
    resources :documents
    # moved to here
    get 'annotations', to: 'annotations#index'
    get 'annotations/:id', to: 'annotations#show'
    ...
    authenticated :user do
        ...
        # moved from here
        #get 'annotations', to: 'annotations#index'
        #get 'annotations/:id', to: 'annotations#show'
        ...
    end
```

I implemented a guest user based on the [Devise Community's recommendation](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Create-a-guest-user), although I used polymorphism instead of creating a whole new function and figuring out all the places I needed to put it in the old code. Of course, I also modified the `create_guest_user` method to actually create a valid guest user for our system.

```
    # app/controllers/application.rb
    def current_user
      if super
        if session[:guest_user_id]
          guest_user.destroy
          session[:guest_user_id] = nil
        end
        super
      else
        guest_user
      end
    end
    helper_method :current_user
    # find guest_user object associated with the current session,
    # creating one as needed
    def guest_user
      begin
        # Cache the value the first time it's gotten.
        @cached_guest_user ||= User.find(session[:guest_user_id] ||= create_guest_user.id)
        #sign_in(:user, @cached_guest_user)
      rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound # if session[:guest_user_id] invalid
         session[:guest_user_id] = nil
         guest_user
      end
    end

    ...

    def create_guest_user
      u = User.create(:firstname => "guest", :lastname => "user", :email => "guest_#{Time.now.to_i}#{rand(99)}@example.com")
      u.save!(:validate => false)
      session[:guest_user_id] = u.id
      # establish guest user credentials
      u.set_roles = ['guest']
      u.rep_group_list << 'public'
      u.save!(:validate => false)
      u
    end
```

Code in context is [here](https://github.com/FinalsClub/Annotation-Studio/blob/32b1175885247696d415626e730535e53735c287/app/controllers/application_controller.rb#L13-L43) and [here](https://github.com/FinalsClub/Annotation-Studio/blob/32b1175885247696d415626e730535e53735c287/app/controllers/application_controller.rb#L72-L86).

With that in place, anonymous users began experiencing a redirect loop to the sign in page. With the proven method of guess-and-check, I figured this out:

```
    # allow guest user to be generated prior to authentication
    def authenticate_user!
      current_user
      super
    end
```

### Results

Guest users are created with all the expected settings, which has been confirmed via console and database. The anonymous/guest users can navigate to the sign in page successfully, sign in, sign out, and once authenticated everything works fine.

However, if the guest user tries to list annotations, the user is redirected to the sign_in page with 401 Unauthenticated and a flash message which reads "You need to sign in or sign up before continuing." The same result occurs if the guest user tries to list documents or view a document.

### Hacks

I removed `before_filter :authenticate_user!` on the Document controller as a test and that seemed to help the situation all around. However, doesn't that pretty much walk around Devise without making use of it?

### Conclusion

Should I simply give up on trying to get Devise to treat guest users as authenticated far enough to hand off decisions to CanCan? I want Devise to handle authentication, but I don't want it to beat on unauthenticated people with the 401 bat.

Is the right solution to remove `:authenticate_user!` from anonymously accessible controller methods? I got the impression from the Devise README that the `:authenticate_user!` filter activates Devise functionality. I'm beginning to suspect it is just a gatekeeper to the majesties that lie beyond the walled authentication paradise.

I thought the gatekeeper was in `routes.rb` via the `authenticated :user` block. What is the difference between `before_filter :authenticate_user!` and the `authenticated :user` block in `routes.rb`? Both seem to get a bit heavy handed with the 401 responses, both seem to stop guest users from accessing resources.

### Related

Related SO questions and Devise community pages which have helped, but not solved, the problem:

- [Stackoverflow: anonymous guest without registering in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5384442/allow-anonymous-guest-user-to-try-out-functionality-without-registering-in-rai)
- [Stackoverflow: Configure Devise/CanCan for Guest Users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14887822/how-to-configure-devisecancan-correctly-for-guest-users)
- [Devise Community: create a Guest User](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Create-a-guest-user)
- [Thoughtbot: Handling Associations on Null Objects](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/handling-associations-on-null-objects)

### Background

I have [a GitHub ticket](https://github.com/FinalsClub/Annotation-Studio/issues/23) with background which I have tried to concisely summarize here. [The original code](https://github.com/FinalsClub/Annotation-Studio) is available on GitHub, as is [my current progress](https://github.com/FinalsClub/Annotation-Studio/tree/guest_role).